# szuflas theorem for ordinary differential equations in Banachspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

For my Bachelor thesis i would like to proof the following statment. Let $E$ be a Banach space and $Q\subset E$. $\alpha$ is the kuratowski measure of noncompactness.

Let $f:[0,T]\times Q\rightarrow E$ be a continous and bounded function. If there exists a $L\geq 0$ so that $$\alpha(f([0,T]\times A))\leq L\alpha(A)$$

for every bounded $A\subset Q$, then the cauchy Problem

$$x'(t)=f(t,x(t))$$
with $$ x(0)=x_0$$
has a solution.

This theorem was proofed by Szufla in
S. Szufla, Some remarks on Ordinary Differential Equations in Banach Spaces, Bull.
Acad. Pol. Sci., sc. math, astr., phys., 16 (1968), 795-800.

I really cant find the paper anywhere. Does someone know where I can find it or how to proof it?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Sorry i have edited it the right way now.

Comment: I know a survey paper on extensions of Szufla's Theorem. It has moreover a comprehensive list of references, yet the paper is in german. Maybe it is helpful somehow: http://fe.math.kobe-u.ac.jp/FE/FE_pdf_with_bookmark/de/fe35-199-222/fe35-199-222.pdf

Comment: A proof can be found in the book of Klaus Deimling: Ordinary Differential Equations in Banach Spaces, LNM 596, Springer (1977), Theorem 2.2

Comment: Ahh thank you! That helps me a lot!